# get data match with extra field value using wp_query for custom post

Tags: wp-query

I added post_meta 'batch' to 'assignment' custom post as follows:

```
update_post_meta( $id, 'batch', strip_tags($_POST['batch']));
```

Now I am trying to retrieve this data as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'assignment',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$assignments = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I want to get all data having 'batch=2017'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your WP Query arguments like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'assignment',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key'     => 'batch',
    'meta_value'   => '2017',
);
```

For multiple post meta you can use meta_query like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'assignment',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'color',
            'value'   => 'blue',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'year',
            'value' => '2017',
        )
    ),
);
```

Comment: If I want to set multiple meta_key and value, how can I do this?. i.e: I want to get data of batch='2017' and 'dept=EEE' and 'section=A'

Comment: Use meta_query argument like this:

`'meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'key'     => 'color',
   'value'   => 'blue',
  ),
        array(
            'key' => 'year',
            'value' => '2017',
        )
 ),`

Comment: @hamdirizal You should edit your answer to reflect the comment for multiples.

Comment: Use `relation => 'AND'` inside `meta_query` array.
Here is a sample screenshot taken from codex: https://i.gyazo.com/5f903509f342b1c974227eba1b5314bc.png

Answer (score 2):

First of all, creating a custom taxonomy named "batch" and creating required terms with it would have made this very easy.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'assignment',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$assignments = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $assignments->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $assignments->have_posts() ) {
            $assignments->the_post();
           $batch = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'batch', true );
           if($batch == 2017){
              echo get_the_title();
           }
    }

}
```